# Issue found: Use of VpnService is not documented in the app description

Tags: android

Please document the use of VpnService in the app description and explain why VpnService is needed with details of relevant features in the app.
Document use of the VpnService in the Google Play listing, and
Encrypt the data from the device to VPN tunnel end point, and

how to solve this issue on google play console my app approved with issues please help

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSQoZ4CcyEwQRTmFYAKJfRu00jjaWkUQgtzxcS3w_dEimAFLEiOPaU-edU88zN2yT_lk6DcLDmSNHl-/pub please open this link i attached detailed screenshots

Answer (score 0):

As per the new Policy introduced (starting Nov 1, 2022), you must submit the declaration form, now available in Play Console, by January 2023 to avoid further enforcement.

You have to submit a VPN Service declaration form, also make sure your app provides VPN as core functionality and you encrypt the data in the tunnel, a video sample, and a few more questions.

Further please refer to this document:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12564964?hl=en#zippy=%2Cguidance-for-video-showcasing-your-apps-prominent-disclosure

A complete guide to filling out that form and a set of relevant answers are provided by Google.